# Rotate an oval SVG object

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to animate my oval shaped image to rotate at a fixed angle so that the outline rotates around an area without changing the area's shape.

How do I do that? Can I use only one image or do I need several small images following an oval shaped path?

This is what i've done ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13a67b0f/)) , as you can see the area is changing shape accordingly to the rotation

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80"
     xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/gTlsQx4.png">
  <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                    attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="0 180 50"
                    to="360 180 50"
                    dur="4s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</image>  
</svg>
```

[Image for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FsiR.jpg)

Comment: You basically want the gear to look as though it is spinning while at an angle, correct?

Comment: Questions seeking code help  - See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At least show us what you have tried.

Comment: @hopkins-matt Yeah correct.

Comment: @Paulie_D Well what I've tried is in the image, rotating the image using Transform css.

Comment: Well if you demo that we might be able to help further

Comment: @Paulie_D made a demo, as you can see the oval doesn't spin at an angle

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a graphics genius but I'm pretty sure this can't be done with what you have.  If you take away the animation and examine the PNG itself, you'll notice the gear is already distorted in a fixed, [two-point perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)) manner-- the gear is stretching "away" from us, the viewer.

But the image itself is 2D, and no matter how you rotate it in SVG or CSS or Canvas, the gear will always stretch the same way.

If there is a solution, it would involve some serious image warping at key points in the animation, and performing warps on a rasterized image will always degrade the visual fidelity.

Here are some alternatives:

- There's the good old stand-by: GIF animation of a 3D animation of the gear performing a full rotation.
- You can slice up a 3D animation into a series of 2D frames, then smash them together into a sprite sheet, then animate it with JavaScript.
- You could use Flash.
- You could experiment with WebGL.

Comment: How would you go about with the flash alternative?

Comment: GIF is probably the easiest solution and most supported (other than some mobile platforms). Flash has the same support issues of GIF, but Flash is being attacked more by the day (http://www.wired.com/2015/07/adobe-flash-player-die/). 3D & JS or WebGL probably give you the best support on modern browser but would be more time consuming than a GIF.

Answer (score 1):

Fun question. I solved it by skewing an outside container using a transform matrix and then rotating the inner image. Your svg animation is a wonky for this, so I used a different cog from font awesome:

http://jsfiddle.net/psd32q68/2/

```
div{
    font-size:84px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:150px;
transform: matrix3d(0,-0.5,1.00,0,0.50,0.87,0.00,.003,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1);
-webkit-transform: matrix3d(0,-0.5,1.00,0,0.50,0.87,0.00,.003,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1);
-moz-transform: matrix3d(0,-0.5,1.00,0,0.50,0.87,0.00,.003,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1);
-o-transform: matrix3d(0,-0.5,1.00,0,0.50,0.87,0.00,.003,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1);
-ms-transform: matrix3d(0,-0.5,1.00,0,0.50,0.87,0.00,.003,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1);


}
span{
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

--

```
   <div>
        <span class="fa fa-cog"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your cog is drawn in perspective, so you can't use normal rotation and expect it to look right.

What you have to do is draw the SVG as a flat cog and then you can use a CSS 3D transform to add a perspective projection to the rotating cog.

Here is a working example:

```css
svg
{
    margin: 100px;
    transform: matrix3d(0.9, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.01, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.9, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.01, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-transform: matrix3d(0.9, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.01, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -o-transform: matrix3d(0.9, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.01, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -ms-transform: matrix3d(0.9, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.01, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <g stroke="black" fill="none" transform="translate(50,50)">
        <g>
            <circle r="38" stroke-width="8"/>
            <line x1="38" x2="49" stroke-width="16"/>
            <line x1="38" x2="49" stroke-width="16" transform="rotate(45)"/>
            <line x1="38" x2="49" stroke-width="16" transform="rotate(90)"/>
            <line x1="38" x2="49" stroke-width="16" transform="rotate(135)"/>
            <line x1="38" x2="49" stroke-width="16" transform="rotate(180)"/>
            <line x1="38" x2="49" stroke-width="16" transform="rotate(225)"/>
            <line x1="38" x2="49" stroke-width="16" transform="rotate(270)"/>
            <line x1="38" x2="49" stroke-width="16" transform="rotate(315)"/>
            <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform"
                              type="rotate" from="0" to="360"
                              dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```